# Regular expression - only digits, dots,commas and first character should be $

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I would like to have a regex for the following expression

```
$123,456,789
$1.23
$123
```

what i have done so far is if use enter `123456789` i will convert this to dollar format as follows `$123,456,789.00`

But i would like to valid the above values if he enters in a text box. I would like to allow only `.` with the numeric values. The `$` symbol will come after my conversion but at the time of leaving i would like to validate the text box as per the requirement any idea please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
^\$?\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d{1,2})?$
```

See it [here online on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2uq4r)

The `$` at the start is optional. The 1 to 3 digits, then can be groups of 3 digits separated by commas, at last an optional 1 or two digit fraction.

Important are the anchors `^` and `$` they ensure, that the complete string is matched and not only a part of the string.

**Bugfix**: Also important, the `.` needs to be escaped, to be matched literally, I added this to my Regex.

**Extension**

If the `,` are not mandatory and you want also e.g. `1000` to be valid, I added an alternation to my regex:

```
^\$?(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*|\d+)(?:\.\d{1,2})?$
```

See it [here online on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2uq4o)

Comment: Can i stop the user with out entering digits after `.` if it exceeds `2`

Comment: @Vivekh sorry I don't understand your question. The `{1,2}` says minimum 1 at most 2 digits. if you also want to allow 0 digits, change it to `{0,2}`, if you want to allow more than 2 `{1,5}` or leave the second part blank to allow infinite numbers `{1,}` (but than you can change this part to `*` or `+`)

Comment: Can i block the user with out entering values after `.` if maximum exceeds

Answer (score 1):

`\$(\d{1,3},)*(\d{1,3})(\.\d+)?`

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
^\$\d{1,3}(,\d{1,3})*(\.\d+)?$
```

Answer (score 1):

My proposal (untested):

```
\$(\d{1,3})(,\d{3})*(\.\d+)?
```

we require a dollar, followed by a up to 3 digits.

then there might come more exactly 3-digit long groups.

at the end there might be a comma followed by at least one digit (or no comma and no digits)

Answer (score 1):

Why not to use common approach for formatting and use appropriate IFormatProvider? Have no idea why do you need regex here...

```
    public static string GetFormattedCurrency(decimal value)
    {
        var formatInfo = new NumberFormatInfo
                            {
                                CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ".",
                                CurrencyGroupSeparator = ",",
                                CurrencyGroupSizes = new[] { 3 },
                                CurrencySymbol = "$"
                            };

        return value.ToString("C", formatInfo);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this

`[$]?(?:\d\,?){0,}(?:\.\d*)?`